# Posting back to calling page from popup page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I am sure this has been asked before, but all of the links I find have to do with posting data to a popup page.

In my case I am trying to return two values/variables from the popup page back to the orginal page.

My effort thus far was to create two session variables in the popup page code behind, and then refresh the first page when the popup was closed. I'm not sure how best to do this. I do not want a fullpage refresh, I just want two textboxes to show the values of each of the session variables.

If I use the postback URL on my close button, my codebehind never fires to populate my session variables and it opens another instance of my calling page.

If someone has a link or tutorial to show this I would be very greatful.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these links which answered my question allowing me to solve this problem with ASP/VB not JavaScript, JSON or XML.

http://asp-net.wonderhowto.com/how-to/implement-cross-page-postback-asp-net-214606/

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-implement-a-cross-page-postback-in-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't understand that returning value to the parent does need a session variable ?

Well you can pass the values to the parent in either json or XML or array, all you need is a piece of JavaScript which is window.parent and you can call the JavaScript method on the parent.

If your requirement is to save it in server session you can do whatever you are doing currently

Comment: I was hoping to avoid JavaScript and certainly JSON and XML. What would the JavaScript array look like? Is there no way to handle this directly through ASP? I do have it saving to session variables, but not sure how to set the specific textbox values.

Comment: Well an upvote would help, anyways what you are trying to do is at the client side , so ASP would not help much

Comment: How could I do this in JavaScript? I guess if I could do a partial page refresh on just the two textbox fields. This should work. I was hoping to do just that without JavaScript.